# how to read non standard json file using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following json file format.

```
{
  "browser": "firefox",
  "dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_35_PM"
}
{
  "browser": "firefox",
  "dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_36_PM"
}
```

as per requirement I cannot change it format, but I have to read this I know we can provide [ and ] braces and separate each element by , but I cant do this, my source file is having above format only.

so how can I read such file?

Is there any way to read such file and convert whole file content to valid json formatted content?

Comment: yes @Ehsan but Its source file...how do I read it?

Comment: You'll have to read it in as a String and then manually parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
  debugger;
  var input = '{  "browser": "firefox",  "dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_35_PM"  }  {    "browser": "firefox",    "dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_36_PM"  }';

  input = input.replace('}', '},');
  input = '[' + input + ']';

  var _json = JSON.parse(input);

  for (var i = 0; i < _json.length; i++)
    alert(_json[i].browser);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but if you have nested object inside will not work

Answer (score 2):

If the file is *exactly* as you've presented it, then you can convert it into valid JSON and parse it.

```
var contents = JSON.parse("[" + fileContents.replace("}\n", "},\n", "g") + "]");
```

However, **don't do this**. If the invalid JSON file is being generated, look for ways to fix the code that's generating it. If it's a static file, fix it before continuing. Requirements are rarely set in stone.