# split this java script string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string

```
{
  "browser": "firefox",
  "dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_35_PM"
}
{
  "browser": "firefox",
  "dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_36_PM"
}
```

I want to get elements betwen opening `{` and closing `}` braces.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: You must live under a rock or something. This is JSON and you can _parse_ it into an object using `JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: Dear @Bojangles you right but I have json file which is not in standard format..but I have to read it. I am doing read file make it proper json format and go

Comment: and if u see its format its not valid json format

Comment: I'm wondering why an 800 rep user is asking a question like this

Comment: Not standard format? Why? If its so close to being JSON why isn't it JSON? Please don't tell me you're building it manually. Your example above is **one character away from being valid JSON**

Comment: @rpax I am java developer...

Comment: @Bojangles my original problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947849/how-to-read-non-standard-json-file-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @Bojangles I try to read that json file but I am getting parser error.

Comment: @rpax I am wondering how 1947 repo person dont understand the problem and comment

Comment: Me too. And as @Bojangles says, your example is one character away from being a valid JSON. How are you receiving this json?

Comment: I am reading json file lie this    $.ajax({
                    url: "test-results/reports.json",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {
                     String jsonData=data;

Comment: If _always_ look like this, you can add an extra ','. Whenever you find a single '}'

Comment: Anyway, Now I see that this question is not as silly I thought. +1

Comment: Do you have control over how the "JSON" is generated in the first place? If so, I would suggest that you fix that. It's misleading to have a URI that suggests it returns a JSON-formatted output when it doesn't.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question?

Answer (score 1):

It looks quite like a JSON encoded objects, but i see there are some incongruences,
Please pay attention at the little edits in you starting string:

```
JSON.parse('[{"browser": "firefox","dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_35_PM"},{"browser": "firefox","dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_36_PM"}]');

//this will convert your string to an actual javascript object..
```

EDIT:

If your json in not proper encoded, you'll have to fix here and there offcourse.. you must add

- enclosing square brackets: `[{ ... }]`
- a comma after every object , `{}, {}`

You can accomplish that with this code

**assume that var_string will contain your string..**

```
var_string = var_string.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); //removing line breaks;

var_string += '[' + var_string + ']'; //adding square brackets

var_string = var_string.replace(/}{/g, "},{"); //adding commas

var_string = JSON.parse(var_string); //parsing object
```

[Json Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Syntax)

Comment: This is not answering the question at all

Comment: i'm editing since the question has been cleared up in a second moment

Comment: @rpax Why we are so nervous :).. this is a fantastic community! let's help each other!

Comment: what happens if the json contains `{` inside ? . `"key": "{"`, for example?

Comment: {
  "browser": {"x":"hello"},
  "dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_35_PM"
}

it's still going to work, but theese are assumption because we don't actually know everything about the input string. @rpax

Comment: ok, it's a correct answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Sanjay, with all the disclaimers already offered about using regex, since you did ask what regex could do for you, here is an expression that would match the two tokens in each of your elements. It assumes that each element only has two tokens, so let us know if that is not the case.

```
{\s*"([^"]*)":\s*"([^"]*)",\s*"([^"]*)":\s*"([^"]*)"
```

1. The first token's name is captured to Group 1, its value is captured to Group 2.
2. The second token's name is captured to Group 3, its value is captured to Group 4.

In the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sS8cW0), look a the Groups in the lower right panel.

**What the regex means**

The top right panel of the demo has a token-by-token explanation.

**How to use the regex**

This is probably obvious for you, but here is sample code to retrieve the values (see output in [code demo](http://js.do/code/38848)):

```
<script>
var subject = '{ \
  "browser": "firefox", \
  "dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_35_PM" \
} \
{ \
  "browser": "firefox", \
  "dateTime": "28_May_2014_03_36_PM" \
} \
';
var regex = /{\s*"([^"]*)":\s*"([^"]*)",\s*"([^"]*)":\s*"([^"]*)"/g;
var match = regex.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    document.write("First token name: ",match[1],"<br />");
    document.write("First token value: ",match[2],"<br />");
    document.write("Second token name: ",match[3],"<br />");
    document.write("Second token name: ",match[4],"<br />");
    match = regex.exec(subject);
}

</script>
```